# PC ignores Windows-BOOTED USB and continues UBUNTU

Tags: windows, bios

I installed Ubuntu but now I want to uninstall it. I booted my USB and I was going to install Windows but when I restarted my laptop, nothing happened. It just continued to Ubuntu. I already listed my USB on the top in the BIOS but still it ignores my USB and continues to Ubuntu. I tried my USB on another laptop which already got Windows and the USB worked as a charm! How can I fix this? I'm sure its not my USB's problem, its something with Ubuntu or BIOS. Help me install Windows and fix this problem. Note: I'm new so please, any replies with detailed and with simple-English (I mean not that much  advanced English) would be greatly appreciated.
My laptop is by Lenevo.
Sorry for bad english.
Edit: Other question didn't solved my problem, so somehow this ain't duplicate
Edit: I booted USB with Rufus from another laptop.

Comment: windows bootable USB is made by which software? you need to check BIOS settings to see this bootable USB. if you have option to get Boot menu instead of prioritizing USB in the first list.

Comment: @PRATAP Check the edited question.

Comment: problem could be UEFI and BIOS mode of booting from this USB. check if you can get into Boot Menu Option instead of going to BIOS Settings and select the vice-versa USB & UEFI USB.

Comment: can you share your laptop or Mother Board model number?

Comment: @PRATAP UEFI/Legacy Boot is set to: Legacy only

Comment: Change it to UEFI and see, this will maximum solve the thing. when you get the Boot Menu Option, you will see USB and UEFI USB. you should selct UEFI USB.

Comment: @PRATAP Are you sure? I don't wanna get messed up with things since my brother is gone on a vacation (He's a expert) and if I do anything wrong, I'll just get my PC messed up and will be bored cause my PC will be ripped. So please confirm that it wouldn't mess anything.

Comment: @Kulfy Eh which one?

Comment: @James Rogers Changing Legacy to UEFI and UEFI to Legacy is under the control of BIOS Settings. So nothing to worry.

Comment: @Kulfy Also, my PC wasn't creating this problem before. So should I still try it in UEFI mode? And does that button have a logo? If it does, what it looks like?

Comment: Yeah. Sure. UEFI might solve it

Comment: @Kulfy How does that button looks like?

Comment: @Kulfy Its Lenevo B590

Comment: Oh!! your laptop is pretty old. Kindly ignore that comment. That button in G or Y series. Same work is done by F12. Just hit F12 as soon as laptop starts booting up. A boot menu will appear. If it lists your USB then just boot it. If not try changing BIOS from legacy to UEFI.

Comment: How to install Windows is off topic here.

Comment: @Kulfy and others who helped me, Thanks guys, I'm using Windows 10 right now. Thanks for helping! By the way, add your solution as a answer, maybe it'll help someone, someday? Changing the UEFI to UEFI only mode did the trick.